# How to filter and deliver a message in Procmail

Tags: email, procmail

I rewrite the subject line for certain incoming mails depending on TO: field:

```
:0fhw
* ! ^TO_user@domain\.com\>
* ^TO_[^<>@ ]+@domain\.com\>
* ^Subject:\/.+
| /usr/local/bin/formail -I"Subject: [SPAM]$MATCH"
```

The above code (from my earlier question [procmail rewrite subject line if email recipient user fails match test](https://serverfault.com/questions/1098742/procmail-rewrite-subject-line-if-email-recipient-user-fails-match-test)) works perfectly - if I get mail from something OTHER THAN user@domain.com, the subject line is rewritten as [SPAM] (original subject)

But I would like to do multiple conditionals like this - the working block, above, will be the final one, but before that, I'd like to rewrite the subject line if the TO matches a different address.

So I added this block just above it:

```
:0fh
* ^TO_special@domain\.com
* ^Subject:\/.+
| /usr/local/bin/formail -I"Subject: [SPECIAL]$MATCH"
$DEFAULT
```

... and this works - emails sent to 'special@domain.com' get their subject line rewritten.

The problem is, Procmail doesn't stop - it moves onto the *next* block and rewrites it again.  So emails sent to `special@domain.com` get their subject lines rewritten as:

[SPAM] [SPECIAL] Original subject line blah blah

Why is this?  Why doesn't the `$DEFAULT` action at the end of the first block cause Procmail to halt processing for that piece of email?

How can I match the new block and **stop** processing that piece of mail and just be done with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$DEFAULT` at the end is a syntax error. You can't specify multiple actions on the same recipe.

What you can do is split it into two recipes; or, in this case, simply combine the rewriting and the delivery.

```
:0:
* ^TO_special@domain\.com
* ^Subject:\/.+
| /usr/local/bin/formail -I"Subject: [SPECIAL]$MATCH" >>$DEFAULT
```

This no longer has the `fh` flags because we want to push the whole message through (not just the headers, which `h` does) and we want to deliver, not capture the results of the pipeline back into Procmail (which `f` does).

This assumes that `$DEFAULT` is a file, not a directory; and thus we also add a second `:` to specify locking.

If you wanted to specify two actions under a single set of conditions, you can use braces with multiple recipes inside them. Each recipe can have zero or more conditions but only one action.

```
:0
* ^TO_special@domain\.com
* ^Subject:\/.+
{
    :0fhw
    | formail -I"Subject: [SPECIAL]$MATCH"

    :0:
    $DEFAULT
}
```

but in this case that's an unnecessary complication.

(It would perhaps also be more idiomatic to move the `^Subject:` condition to the `formail` recipe where it logically belongs, but this is just a tangent anyhow.)

Also tangentially, perhaps make sure your `PATH` is correct right at the start of your `.procmailrc` so you can avoid spelling out the full path to external utilities like `formail`.

Comment: Please notice brief update wrt locking just now. And thanks for the accept.